# How do Rich Text Editors in HTML documents achieve their rich text formatting?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, richtext

Could you please explain how the text in the textarea gets styled in rich-text editors? I've tried to style text in the form but it doesn't change.

Is it JS that recognizes characters typed by the user? How's that done?

---

#### Edit:

After a bit of research (Google rules!), I've found some excellent information. For others who might be interested, these links were very helpful to me:

- http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column11/
- http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column12/

Comment: Can you show us some code please?

Comment: joerage: for just 4 questions ... while certainly it isn't nice it's still a way different thing than with people that didn't accept answers for tens or hundreds of questions.

Comment: @Johannnes: Its more like 12 questions asked.  And if you count the only answer he supplied which was actually another question, than that makes 13.

Comment: No. Well, there's some concept? Okie, whatever. Shall I learn the concept too?

Comment: Badly worded question and an improper attitude from the OP: I vote to close (which I'll reverse as soon as the question gets rephrased).

Comment: I only know Russian well. I wish I knew English well too.

Comment: It seems I can't retract my close vote (which I tried after you added a bit more info to your question). I don't think it'll get closed though.

Comment: I only talk about JS. This is a place for programmers, not for bla-bla-bla lovers.

Comment: Ah, I see: asking a coherent, clear question equals "bla-bla-bla" in your book. I'll be off now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is that what you're looking at is typically NOT an actual `<textarea>`.  It's a `<div>` or `<span>` made to look like a text area.  **A regular HTML textarea doesn't have individual formatting of the text.**

"Rich-Text editors" will have controls that modify the contents of the span/div with regular html markup (`<strong>`, `<em>`, etc.) to emulate a full-blown rich text editor

Comment: It's difficult to find out what TinyMCE does, but it uses a textarea in this example: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php

Comment: Another common technique is to layer an iframe over top of the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the rich text editor will provide a variable to specify a style sheet in. That style sheet will then be loaded and applied to the textarea (Most, if not all, rich text editors use a IFRAME to display the editor in, and obviously styles specified in the main document won't apply to it.)

Comment: As understand JS replaces the textarea with a IFRAME... Is an iframe sort of the textarea?

Comment: In IFRAME is a window to a separate document. The textarea is essentially meaningless, it is used only as a data container so that the edited content can be saved through a form. 
What WYSIYWYG editor are you using?

Comment: I don't use any... So, is it JS that recognizes characters typed by the user? How's it done?

Answer (score 0):

It's a `textarea` when you send the HTML to the user but the editor replaced it with a `div` when it can start.

This way, the code gracefully degrades: Users with unsupported web browsers or disabled JavaScript can still edit the text in the `textarea` while all the other users get a nice rich text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the TEXTAREA contents are used as the HTML source for the IFRAME.