# JavaScript: mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript

I have two div boxes: one that is large is the parent to the other that is small. With propeties offsetX and offsetY, I find out the coorinates of the mouse pointer. I only need coordinates relative to the large box, but when the mouse pointer is over the small box, coordinates are figured out relative to this small box. How do I get coordinates relative to the large box even though the mouse pointer is over the small box?

Comment: "how would I state ... to only look relative the 'theLargeBox' element?" Math.

Comment: Are you from Italian mafia? What's wrong with that?

Comment: To be honest, after this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815611/how-do-rich-text-editors-in-html-documents-achieve-their-rich-text-formatting I promised myself to ignore your posts in the future. I forgot that this time but will remember in the future unless you show a bit more politeness and concern for other SO'ers.

Comment: Well, I'm off. You can stay on subject with yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that is because the small box is absolutely or relatively positioned (`position: absolute` `position: relative`). Can you change that so that only the parent is absolutely positioned?

Otherwise, the JS Frameworks should offer everything you need to convert relative into absolute positions, and correlate them to the mouse cursor.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The small box is absolutely positioned. Wouldn't there be a way? Frameworks are evil! I know how to, but that's a bit ugly, I think.

Comment: You would have to add the absolute `left` and `top` coordinates of the parent element of the mouse cursor position. (probably this.parentElement.style.left..)

Comment: Better to deal with x and y if the target get changed.